# How to use SSL on IIS 7 server by default?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2008

I want to use SSL on my IIS 7 server by default

I want to use SSL on my IIS 7 server by default, how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "by default"? If you install & bind a certificate HTTPS is enabled ..

Comment: It means I want to force all users to use ssl

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 7 when you click on the website, there is an icon for SSL Settings. Check the box that says Require SSL.

If you want to redirect users from non-ssl to ssl automatically, you'll need to add a redirect rule. Download and install the URL rewrite module from here: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite and then add this rule into your web.config under

```
<configuration><system.webserver><rewrite><rules>

<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```